# serial port read/write returns too early

Tags: c++, serial-port, at-command

```
I have written a small and simple serial port read/write application to connect to my modem and to run commands. There is a problem. The program works perfectly for the most part but when the command takes a bit of time to execute and respond, the program acts strangely. Here is my code:

void write (char cmd[256]) {
    int n_written = 0;
    char atcmd [259];
    sprintf (atcmd, "%s\r\n", cmd);

    n_written = write( fd, &atcmd, strlen(atcmd) );
    printf ("WROTE: %d\n", n_written);
}

void read (char * cmdresp) {
    int n = 0;
    char response[1024];
    memset(response, 0 , sizeof response);

    n = read( fd, &response, sizeof (response) );
    if (n < 0) {
        printf ("ERROR=%d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    } else if (n == 0) {
        printf ("Read nothing!\n");
    } else {
        printf ("READ: %s\n", response);
        strcpy (cmdresp, response);
    }
}

void manage_transaction (char * message, char * response) {
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    write (message);

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &rfds);
    int retval = select(fd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (retval == -1) {
    perror("select()");
    } else if (retval) {
    if (FD_ISSET(fd, &rfds) ) {
        usleep(200000);
        read(response);
    }
    } else {
        printf("No data within five seconds.\n");
    }
}
```

Here is two successive runs, one successful one unsuccessful:

```
Successful:
AT> AT+CGSN
Client ConnectedHere is the message: AT+CGSN

WROTE: 11
READ: AT+CGSN
123456789012345

OK

AT+CGSN
123456789012345

OK

FAILED:
AT> ATD11234567890;
Here is the message: ATD11234567890;

WROTE: 19
READ: ATD11234567890;
AT> 1234567890;
```

<<-- If I press an enter key or send another message the rest of the message comes through:

```
Here is the message:

WROTE: 4
READ:
OK


OK
AT>
```

Am I missing something? How can I fix this problem?

Any ideas is greatly appreciated.

*********** EDIT ***************
Here are the open and config codes:

```
int open_port(void)
{
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB2");
    }
    else {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
        printf("port is open.\n");
    }
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH);

    return fd;
}

void config () {
struct termios tty;
struct termios tty_old;
memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
if ( tcgetattr ( fd, &tty ) != 0 ) {
    printf ("ERROR=%d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}

tty_old = tty;

/* Set Baud Rate */
cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B115200);
cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B115200);

tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
tty.c_iflag     &= ~INPCK;
tty.c_iflag     |=  (IGNBRK | BRKINT); 

tty.c_iflag     |= IGNPAR;

tty.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;

tty.c_iflag &= ~IXON;
tty.c_iflag &= ~ISTRIP;

tty.c_iflag &= ~INLCR;
tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNCR;
tty.c_cflag     &= ~CRTSCTS;            // no flow control
tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  0;                  // read doesn't block
tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  0;                  // 5 seconds read timeout
tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines
tty.c_iflag     &= ~(IXON |IXOFF|IXANY); /* no XON/XOFF flow control */
tty.c_oflag     &= ~(IXON |IXOFF|IXANY); /* no XON/XOFF flow control */
tty.c_oflag     &= ~(OPOST | ONLCR );
/* Make raw */
cfmakeraw(&tty);

/* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH );
tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH );

int reuse = 1;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse));

if ( (tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&tty) < 0) ) {
    printf ("ERROR=%d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but even though C++ have function overloading I would not recommend naming one of your global functions the same as one of the platform system calls. E.g. `write` or `read`. That will confuse readers and make your code harder to maintain.

Comment: Possibly more related, remember that serial communication is very much streaming with no beginnings or ends of data. That means a single `read` call will retrieve what the system have in its buffers, but it might not be the full "message" that has been sent by the other end of the serial connection. If you have something special you look for as a message "terminator" then you need to read in a loop until you have received it.

Comment: Good point on terminator. The messages either terminate with "OK" or "ERROR". However, there are no unsolicited messages enabled. So whatever I write to the port, I should get an answer for, nothing more. However, some commands take longer time to respond and some take less time. I don't know ahead of time what is being issued.

Comment: The read() call does not produce a string either, it kinda works by accident because of the memset() call.  But you're screwed if it ever returns 1024 chars.  You must keep calling read until you get `\n`, glue the responses together and zero-terminate it to make a string.  Most easily done by passing &response[len] and sizeof(response) - 1 where len tracks the cumulative size of the received data.

Comment: I'm not sure how it could work "kinda" by accident. If you could please help me understand this. I expect data bytes in a range of 16-32 bytes only, so the buffer is way too big for what it's needed for. I have my port open with: fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);  and I set cfmakeraw(&tty); ... Would it be useful for me to post the open and configure portions too?

Comment: Your code only *"kinda"* works because you use **select()** to wait for some data to be available, delay another 0.2 seconds, and then perform a non-blocking, non-canonical **read()**.  Since there is somekind of echo (of the written data either locally or from the remote), the full response has to be received and buffered within that 0.2 sec sleep.  A "slow" command such as the ATD dial command did not complete within 0.2 sec.  @Someprogrammerdude -- canonical mode can perform **read()** s of complete lines delimited by `\n` and/or other specified terminator(s).

Comment: OK that makes sense. Can you offer a modification to the code please?